# Proper way to load data from database once on page load in MVC 4 Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I need to get some data from a database and load it into `db` when the page loads initially.  Specifically I cant figure out the right place/way to run this method. If I put it in my `ActionResult Index()`(which is the page the data is displayed on) it works but I end up outputting a duplicate all of my values on each page refresh. What is the right way to do this?

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext();

    public void loadFromTable()
    {
        IEnumerable<Task> tasks = readAllEntities();
        foreach (Task item in tasks)
        {
            db.MyDatas.Add(item);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
    ...
```

Comment: If the result is shared for all sessions, you can use`Cache`. If the data is user specific, you can use `Session`. In both cases I would create some kind of manager the handles putting things in the Cache/Session and when asked for values checks if they exist in Cache/Session and if not, get them from the DB.

Comment: Maybe also you could explain a little more what you are trying to achieve? for me db and database sound quite similar.

Comment: @codea I'm trying to display a sheet of values that I am getting out of a azure table storage database, and my sheet is rendered from the `db` variable.

Comment: @EladLachmi The data is shared. I've never worked with caching in razor before. If you happen to have a link on how to get started that would be very helpful!

Comment: Sorry, I made a noob mistake and read your question without reading the code. Although saving things to Cache is a good idea anyway :) It`s just ASP.NET Cache. Nothing special for DB context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I solved my issue by adding

```
if (db.MyDatas.Count() == 0)
    loadFromTable();
```

to both of my two views. If anyone has a better solution I'd be glad to hear it!

Comment: Works for me! Why over-engineer it!? :) Thanks!